# How can a software company support developer community?

Tags: java

I'm just preparing a local Java User Group meeting to take place in a meeting room provided by my employer so that is how this question came up...

I know that some companies sponsor conferences, some hire open source developers etc. However, are there any other ways in which a software company can support its (local) developer community?

Comment: @Qix this is *far* too old for Programmers.SE migration.  It is also ***far*** too broad of a question for it to be acceptable on the site now.  Please read [What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/40980) to get a better idea of the expectations for questions on Programmers.SE.

Comment: @MichaelT `FFR` = *for future reference*. Wasn't suggesting a migration.

Comment: @Qix and it would be a poor question there that would have gotten closed quite quickly for being too broad of a question by today's standards.

Comment: @MichaelT this could easily fit under `software engineering management` and even maybe `development methodologies and processes`.

Comment: Then it's too broad here, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Offering up your employer's meeting room and taking the time to organize your user group sounds like a good start to me.  The user groups I've attended get consulting companies and recruiters to sponsor meetings with free pizza and raffle prizes in return for a few minutes to pitch attendees at the start of each meeting.  Beyond that, get creative.  Start a website with a forum, invite speakers to talk about new tech, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Locally, one company pays room rent for [BJUG](http://www.boulderjug.org/) and another company pays for pizza during the meetings.